# My default ProgramData path is set to Drive F instead of C (system) for certain programs. How do change it back to normal?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, path, directory-junction, move

Last year I accidentally moved `ProgramData` folder to Drive `F` from `C`. Realizing that I instantly moved it back and things were going normally until it finally caught up to me.

Because of some programs that assumed the wrong path (drive F) as their systemroot and fixated on it, I cannot update, reset or troubleshoot windows properly. The explorer crashes sometimes and some key functions are inaccessible.

Is there anyway I can refresh their system root or change their directory registry manually or automatically?

[image]

Comment: What instructions exactly did you use it to move it originally[?](https://superuser.com/questions/445654/how-to-move-completely-the-programdata-folder-from-one-partition-in-to-another-p)

Comment: None. It was mere an accident with the darg and drop...

Comment: One doesn’t “drag and drop” move ProgramData to another drive, however, your screenshot indicates the Start Menu location was changed not ProgramData

Comment: yeah well, it was originally programdata but after I deleted it, it automatically created a new folder named new folder which acts as their ProgramData I think.

Comment: And whenever I try to move or rename the New Folder, I get error code 0x80070005

Answer (score 0):

You probably did some irreversible actions such as taking ownership of Windows folders,
which is absolutely not a good idea.

My suggestion:

- Uninstall these badly-installed products and ensure that `F:\ProgramData`
  is empty
- [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
  to try and undo the permissions change
- Re-install the uninstalled products.

Comment: I tried to do that yesterday but resetting or repair installing doesn't seem to work. After the process is done it says, "Desktop is not found" and the pc is just stuck on desktop. After rebooting the process undo the changes and gets back to where it was.

Comment: Windows is too destroyed. If In-place Upgrade doesn't work, all that is left is reinstallation from scratch of Windows and all the applications.

Comment: Isnt there any way I can reset the directory to its default? Like from registry or a third party handler program?

Comment: If System Restore is enabled, a weak chance is to rollback Windows to its state before these manipulations were done.

Comment: @CrZero - I linked you to a question with an answer with a potential fix, however, I agree with the conclusion the migration of ProgramData (specifically the way it was done) means it cannot be repaired

Comment: @harrymc - The user made these changes a year ago, the chances of a restoration point from a year ago, is extremely small

Comment: @Ramhound ah which link? Sorry I am new here...

Comment: I wish I had system restore enabled... All I am doing now is using Process Explorer and ShellExView(since I use alot of third party add-ons) to manually identify the problem and rewrite it.

Comment: Also I used up a lot of programs that fixes broken reg and permissions... nothing changed.

Comment: You have nothing to lose, so try this command in an elevated CMD : `icacls "C:\ProgramData" /q /c /t /reset`.

Comment: @Ramhound oh is it the link on the right side? I actually looked that up before creating an account here today. That seemed like a potential answer and encouraged me to join this awesome community.
The path the top answer mentioned there has everything normal in my registry (set everything default to SystemDrive). So I didn't change anything there.

Comment: @harrymc does it reset everything?

Comment: It might reset the permissions, especially returning the ownership to System. If it fails or causes different damage than exists already, you are already on the road to total reinstall. Don't do this command if you can live with your current situation and don't want to take such a risk.

Comment: Even if you had system restore enabled, its enabled by default, you wouldn’t have had a restore point from a year ago