# How to reverse the effect of robocopy junction link command used to change the directory of ProgramData from C to D?

Tags: windows, command-line, symbolic-link, robocopy

I recently followed the following advise to free up space on my C Drive, however, I wasn't able to delete the ProgramData folder after executing the command below. Any idea how I can reverse the effect imposed on my files by this command? I just want everything to go back to normal.

thanks

[I followed the below instructions found in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/445657/1726452)

*emphasized text*

You can change your default ProgramData path to be an alternative drive. Although doing so, all new users that are created will use the new programdata path. So you may end up having two ProgramData folders at the end of the data.
Alternatively, you could use “NTFS Junction Points”. Not many people know of this, but a junction point is a way to force all programs that write to path (C:\ProgramData) to be redirected to (D:\ProgramData). This is how old programs designed for XP can easily work with Vista and Windows 7 new folder locations (Documents and settings replaced with Users).

So you could create a junction point specifically for the tmp directory that is created by the GR.

mkdir D:\ProgramData
robocopy /XJ /MIR "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData"
mklink /J "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData"
The downside is that Windows Update does not work well with program data on a separate drive. See Relocation of the Users directory and the ProgramData directory to a drive other than the drive that contains the Windows directory.

Comment: Which `ProgramData` are you trying to delete?

Comment: Trying to remove C:\ProgramData, and make all the programs that write to that path redirect to D:\ProgramData

Comment: Anyway, right now I am just trying to return things they way they were before running that script

Comment: `C:\ProgramData` will still exist as a junction point not a directory. You can't get rid of it altogether. To undo `RD C:\ProgramData`, `mkdir C:\ProgramData`, copy everything back from `D:\ProgramData`, check everything is working and then delete `D:\ProgramData`