# Hacking a Windows 11 Installation Setup

Tags: windows-installation, disk-image, dism

During Windows 11 installation:

[image]

Obviously `install.wim`'s only image inside is extracted in this "Copying Windows files" stage. Now, this `install.wim`, I wish to replace with my own WIM file containing 2 images spanning 2 drives:

> Program Files, Program Files (x86), Windows — inside C:
>
> PerfLogs, ProgramData, Temp & Users — inside D:

(Yes I've tinkered with splitting these between 2 drives enough to know it works)

So, how do I make the setup iterate through this "Copying Windows files" twice? I don't have experience in cracking installers & such, but I know there should be command in a script:

```
dism apply-image /imagefile:install.wim /applydir:C:\ {/index:1 | /name:"Windows 11 Home"}
```

If so, then achieving this should be a relative cinch.

EDIT:

I may be on a false lead. I've somewhat hex searched an extracted Windows installation ISO & it seems the DISM commands are done with dynamic links rather than the command line shell. I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Your personal need for an answer is unlikely going to be a determination if you receive an answer to your question.  If you receive an answer to this question, it could be hours, days, weeks in the future.  You might have to take the appropriate steps to figure out the problem yourself if you are under a tight deadline.  You might be better off, just booting into WinPE, which is configured to run a custom PowerShell script instead of trying to modify the behavior of Microsoft's installation environment.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but not by editing the installer. You just have to emulate what the installer is doing.

Full step by step guide for doing this with the Users folder - the steps are the same for win11: https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/1964-move-users-folder-location-windows-10-a.html

Recommended reading:

- [Capture and apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-using-a-single-wim?view=windows-11) your WIM image using DISM - the basic steps for installing windows from a .wim file
- [optional] Create a [Data Image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/create-a-data-image-using-dism?view=windows-11) of the files a normal capture does not include, like `D:\mystuff\`.
- Create an [unattend.xml answer file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/update-windows-settings-and-scripts-create-your-own-answer-file-sxs?view=windows-11) to have windows install certain system directories (ProgramData, Users, etc.) to drive D:

Here's an example unattend.xml to give you an idea of how to set up /Users/ on D: and apply your data image onto partition 1 (D:), **but** you should use the Windows SIM to generate these, since the available settings tend to change between windows releases

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
  <settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <FolderLocations>
        <ProfilesDirectory>D:\Users</ProfilesDirectory>
      </FolderLocations>
    </component>
  </settings>
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <ImageInstall>
        <DataImage wcm:action="add">
          <InstallTo>
            <DiskID>0</DiskID>
            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
          </InstallTo>
          <InstallFrom>
            <Path>X:\folder\MyData.wim</Path>
          </InstallFrom>
          <Order>1</Order>
        </DataImage>
      </ImageInstall>
    </component>
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

edit:

- **ProgramData** can be moved the [same way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/desktop/unattend/microsoft-windows-shell-setup-folderlocations-programdata), but is not recommended. It's easier to copy any files to `D:` and [link](https://superuser.com/a/445657/673426) the folder
- **Temp** is just an environment variable, `%TEMP%`, and doesn't need to be set at install
- **PerfLogs** is hardcoded to `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\PerfLogs`, so it will always be on your primary windows partition. You can link it elsewhere the same way as ProgramData

Those steps can be done with a script as part of the unattend.xml using [RunSynchronousCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc722359(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Seems to work well for Users folder (with it's ProfilesDirectory tag), but what about the rest PerfLogs, ProgramData & Temp? Do they also have tags for them?

Comment: @TempusNomen ProgramData does, but it may not work anymore. I've added suggestions for it and the others

Comment: Yeah, every single one of the 4 folders: PerfLogs, ProgramData, Temp & Users, I've moved to D: & linked to from C:. I don't want to go the extra, inelegant work of setting them up differently as you suggest it, so I want them done in the same step.

Comment: @TempusNomen if that's all you're doing, just have unattend.xml run a script after basic installation to copy and link. Or if you do have a second wim for your D: drive, just apply it with the `DataImage` step. Nothing where you move ProgramData is going to be "elegant" lol

Comment: Where do I start learning to do either? A quick brush up so I can decide which to go with?

Comment: For example, I'm leaning to using DataImage, but just to create the above unattend.xml, I have to generate it by Windows SIM, which means I have to install Windows ADK. Is there a shortcut?

Comment: I'm thinking of running along with the XML above, I'll only change what I think needs changing & the rest I leave out, so they'll be on default. At this point, I'm not above throwing & seeing what sticks.

Comment: @TempusNomen There's a decent online generator for basic use 
cases: https://www.windowsafg.com/

Comment: If I customize just the components & tags under `ImageInstall` & leave everything out, then the Windows Setup will behave **exactly** as before, right? But, will unpack DataImage as I customized it.

Comment: @TempusNomen Just try it out on a virtual machine. If it doesn't do what you expect, then check the Setupact.log (full setup log), Setuperr.log (only errors), and Cbs_unattend.log (only unattend steps) from the install. There may be some trial and error involved